# Carrot2 3.9.4 upgrading to Lucene 4.7+

Tags: lucene, carrot2

Getting an error when trying to connect to a Lucene index above 4.7:

Processing error: **org.apache.lucene.index.IndexFormatTooNewException**: Format version is not supported (resource: MMapIndexInput(path="C:\kcp-search-data\kcp-index_2.cfs") [slice=_2_Lucene41_0.doc]): 1 (needs to be between 0 and 0)
org.apache.lucene.index.IndexFormatTooNewException: Format version is not supported (resource: MMapIndexInput(path="C:\kcp-search-data\kcp-index_2.cfs") [slice=_2_Lucene41_0.doc]): 1 (needs to be between 0 and 0)

Any work arounds for this error? Any idea when the next release of Carrot2 with upgraded Lucenee libraries will be released?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The issue has been identified in the Carrot JIRA tracker and it looks like they plan to fix it in version 3.10.0 if I read this correctly.

http://issues.carrot2.org/browse/CARROT-1078

Sorry I don't have better news.

Answer (score 0):

The 3.10.0 is not yet out, but you can try the snapshot binaries from:

http://get.carrot2.org/head/3.10.0-SNAPSHOT/

The snapshot comes with Lucene upgraded to versino 5.0.0, so it should read your index too.

I'll update this reply as soon as the official carrot2 3.10.0 release is available.

Comment: I can get the Workbench v3.10.0 to connect to the new index however when importing the carrot2-core-3.10.0-SNAPSHOT.jar to my project I get a compilation error:

Compilation error: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/carrot2/util/attribute/IBindableDescriptor

Comment: You also need the attributes-binder-1.2.2.jar in your classpath.

Comment: Thanks, Yeah I forgot those Jars. Spoiled by maven haha